# is there a difference in the result from these two algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

these two algorithms are used to check valid member numbers
the first is the one I was given by the company,
the second is one I devised, from my tests I can't see any difference between them functionally,

are there any cases anyone can see where they would return different outputs?

```
test input: 
6014355021355010
or
6014355065446212
or
6014351000254605
```

The check digit is calculated using the first 15 digits as follows:

> 1. Sum the digits in the even numbered positions from left to right
> 2. Multiply each digit in the odd numbered positions (from left to
>      right) by the number 2. If any results
>      are 2 digits, sum the digits into one.
>      Sum the digits from each
>      multiplication into a final result.
> 3. Add the final results of steps 1 and 2.
> 4. Take the last digit of the result from step 3 and subtract from 10 to
>      give the check digit.
> 5. Take the last digit from the 16 Digit number and compare to the check digit
> 6. if they are equal, it is valid

vs

The check digit is calulated using the whole 16 digits as follows:

> 1. Sum the digits in the even numbered positions from left to right
> 2. Multiply each digit in the odd numbered positions (from left to
>      right) by the number 2. If any results
>      are 2 digits, sum the digits into one.
>      Sum the digits from each
>      multiplication into a final result.
> 3. Add the final results of steps 1 and 2.
> 4. Take the final result and Modulus 10
> 5. If the result is 0, it is valid

---

**Update:** 
ok so. I have tried to create both these algorithms in php,
the second one, i have created successfully,
the first however, i can not seem to get to work.

possibly i have read this wrong, but, here is the original brief i was given for the first algorithm:

> ### 16 digit number modulus 10 check digit calculation
>
> The check digit is calculated using the first 15 digits as follows:
>   **1.** Sum the digits in the even numbered positions from left to right
>   
>  **2.** Multiply each digit in the odd numbered positions (from left to right) by the number 2
>   If any results are 2 digits, sum the digits into one.
>   Sum the digits from each multiplication into a final result.
>   
> **3.** Add the final results of steps 1 and 2.
>   
> **4.** Take the last digit of the result from step 3 and subtract from 10 to give the check digit.
>   If the result of step 3 is a multiple of 10, then the check digit will be zero.
>
> ---
>
> **Example** 6014 3590 0000 0928
>   **1.0** 0 + 4 + 5 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 9 = 18
>   **2.0** 6 * 2 = 12 **so** 1 + 2 = 3
>   **2.1** 1 * 2 = 2
>   **2.2** 3 * 2 = 6
>   **2.3** 9 * 2 = 18 **so** 1 + 8 = 9
>   **2.4** 0 * 2 = 0
>   **2.5** 0 * 2 = 0
>   **2.6** 0 * 2 = 0
>   **2.7** 2 * 2 = 4
>   **2.8** 3 + 2 + 6 + 9 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 4 = 24
>   **3.0** 18 + 24 = 42
>   **4.0** The check digit is 10 - 2 = 8
>   **5.0** 8 = the 16th digit (601435900000092[8])

---

**Update2:** 
ok, so i have corrected the algorithm,

also, i should mention, that there are two other checks
if(length of number != 16)
 return 1;
and
if(first 5 characters != 601435)
return 1;

so are there any counters to this?

cheers,
Matt

---

**Algorithm test [php]**

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('fb.csv');
$numbers = explode("\n", $file);

function validate_flybuys($number) {
    $r = array ('o' => '0', 'i' => '1', 'l' => '1', 'e' => '3', ' ' => '');
    $flybuys = trim(strtolower($number));
    $flybuys = str_replace(array_keys($r), $r, $flybuys);
    if('601435' != substr($flybuys, 0, 6) || strlen($flybuys) != 16)
            return 1;
    $evens = 0;
    $odds = '';

    for($i = 0; $i <= 15; $i+=2) {
        $odds .= $flybuys[$i];
        $evens += $flybuys[$i+1];
    }

    $odds = str_split($odds);
    foreach($odds as &$odd) {
        $odd = $odd*2;
        if($odd >= 10) {
            $odd = str_split($odd);
            $odd = $odd[0] + $odd[1];
        }
    }
    return (array_sum($odds)+$evens) % 10;
}

function validate_flybuys2($number) {
    $r = array ('o' => '0', 'i' => '1', 'l' => '1', 'e' => '3', ' ' => '');
    $flybuys = trim(strtolower($number));
    $flybuys = str_replace(array_keys($r), $r, $flybuys);
    if('601435' != substr($flybuys, 0, 6) || strlen($flybuys) != 16)
            return 1;
    $evens = 0;
    $odds = '';

    for($i = 0; $i <= 14; $i+=2) {
        $odds .= $flybuys[$i];
        if($i != 14)
            $evens += $flybuys[$i+1];
    }

    $odds = str_split($odds);
    foreach($odds as &$odd) {
        $odd = $odd*2;
        if($odd >= 10) {
            $odd = str_split($odd);
            $odd = $odd[0] + $odd[1];
        }
    }
    $total = (array_sum($odds))+$evens;
    $total = str_split($total);
    $check = 10 - $total[1];
    $check = $check % 10;
    if($check == substr($flybuys, 15, 1))
        return 0;
    else
        return $check;
}

foreach($numbers as $number) {
    $valid = validate_flybuys($number);
    $valid2 = validate_flybuys2($number);
    if($valid != $valid2 || $valid != 0) {
        echo '<hr />';
        echo 'NUMBER: '.$number.'<br />';
        echo 'V1: '.$valid.'<br />';
        echo 'V2: '.$valid2.'<br />';
    }
}
```

if anyone is interested and comments i can post some sample numbers to test against :)
oh and feel free to optimize the code 8D

Comment: From the brief you added your step 5 of the first algorithm shouldn't be a modulus. It should be an equal check between the calculated check digit and the 16th digit (or a substraction with a followed check if the result is 0). With that change both algorithms are equal thought.

Comment: (Off-topic:) I find it rather interesting that you would spend so much time on a (working) algorithm given to you by your company... is this a case of premature optimization? `:-)`

Comment: (Off-topic:) Nope, this is a case of while i was writing the first one (in php) i accidentally created the second one, and was curious as to see if there was anything different, considering this has to validate 3.5 million cards in the next month 8D.  

which one is better in your mind?

Comment: Not sure where the 5th step comes from in your description of the original algorithm... I think they rather check if it *is* the last digit, but only you boss can tell you that...

Comment: @Hailwood Do you have any example numbers from which you know they are valid and have a `7` as the last digit? It should be easier too verify which variant is correct with such numbers.

Comment: @Hailwood: I'm all for curiosity, and this here is a nice puzzle. When it comes to deciding which is better _in practice_, however, I'd just go for the original one, mainly because if the algorithm turns out to be wrong, noone can blame you for it. If you end up using your algorithm, you'll have to be ready to defend it (e.g. with a sound proof that the algorithms are equivalent). But that might not be enough: Telling from my experience, some enraged bosses aren't going to accept even solid arguments, all they'll see is that you changed something (assumed to be) correct for no good reason.

Comment: it seems like what you are after is a basic credit card verification algorithm.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: This proof only works if the step 5 and 6 of the first algorithm are an equal check instead of a modulus calculation. The equal check seems to be meant by the original brief as mentioned in the comments.

EDIT2: I think the first algorithm should look like this. But you should better verify this, maybe from the one who gave you the original brief.

> 1. *Sum the digits in the even numbered positions from left to right*
> 2. *Multiply each digit in the odd numbered positions (from left to right) by the number 2. If any results are 2 digits, sum the digits into one. Sum the digits from each multiplication into a final result.*
> 3. *Add the final results of steps 1 and 2.*
> 4. *Take the last digit of the result from step 3 and substract from 10 to give the check digit.*
> 5. *Take the last digit of the 16digit-number and if it is the same as the computed check digit the number is valid*

---

To verifiy mathematically that both algorithms are equal you can use [congruency](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html).

Let's say `a` is the sum from step 3 of the first algorithm, `b` is the sum of step 3 of the second algorithm and `c` is the 16th digit (the check digit).

Than the difference between `a` and `b` is that `c` is added to `b` but not to `a`, which means:

```
a ≡ b - c mod 10
```

The check from the first algorithm is performed by substracting `a` from 10 and check if it is congruent `c` for modulus 10. (for addition and substraction it doesn't matter when the modulus is performed)

```
10 - a ≡ c mod 10
```

this is equal to:

```
-a ≡ c mod 10
```

Now you can substitute `a` with the first one, which results in

```
-(b - c) ≡ c mod 10
```

this is equal to:

```
c - b ≡ c mod 10
```

and this is equal to:

```
-b ≡ 0 mod 10
b ≡ 0 mod 10
```

and that is the check, which is performed in the second algorithm. So both algorithms returns the same result.

Comment: Then you can for sure prove my counter example of 0000000000000257 wrong?! Not sure what you proved here, but not the algorithm obviously.

Comment: From the originaly brief added in the update, i read it that way that the calculated check digit, must be equal with the 16th digit. Thats also what makes sense for generating a 16th crc-like digit to proof correctness. So for your example the sum is 2+1=3 and the check digit is 10-3=7 which is equal to the 16th digit.

Comment: Yes, the equal check makes more sense. Now, this was a refreshing flashback of maths, so +1. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Edit2: Please see my other answer with a counter example with the correct algorithms.

Edit: I was using 15 not 16 numbers in the second algorithm.

<strike>They are not equivalent.</strike>

Take 383838383838383-6  which is valid for first algorithm, but the second algorithm gives 4 as the check digit != 0.

Edit: Sums are 56 for the even part and 48 for odd, sum is 104.

Comment: For this example both algorithms say the number is valid. For the second alogrithm you take the whole 16 digits! So sum for even part is 62 and for uneven is 48, which is 110 and 110%10==0.

Comment: Your test number doesn't have 16 digits. How can you compare the algorithms without the complete digits? What's more, the result from step 2 (calculate sum for odd digits) should be 45, not 48: 2*3 + 2*3 + 2*3 + 2*3 + 2*3 + 2*3 + 2*3 + 3 = 45 (where the last 3 results from 2*6 = 12, whose digits are summed into 3).

Comment: @stakx i think he meant 3838 3838 3838 383 - 6

Comment: Right, missed the last 3 before the check digit. But it's wrong anyway :-)

Comment: The test number suggested by rudi-moore above works with both algorithms.

Comment: Please see my new answer with a counter example.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms are **different**:

Take `0000000000000257`

The original algorithm says it's not valid: Sum of even numbered digits is 2, the odds sum is 1 => total of 3. 10-3 = 7. 257 MOD 7 = 5 != 0   => Not valid

You algorithm sums even to 9, odds to 1 => total 10. 10 MOD 10 == 0   => Valid.

So they are **not equivalent**

qed. :-)

Comment: It should be 7 mod 7 = 0, which is valid.
But i conform with you that there are counter examples for the first posted algorithms. `0600 0000 0000 000 - 8` for example. sum for 1st algorithm is 6. 10-6=4. 8 mod 4 = 0 -> valid. sum for 2nd algorithm 14. 4 != 0 -> not valid. Thats why i added a comment. Because i think the modulus from the first algorithm should be an equal check (the originally brief says that too thought). For that example: 8 != 4 -> not valid. With that equal check instead of a modulus both are equal, which i proofed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your php code has some problems.

`$check = 10 - $total[1];` is only valid if the total sum is a 2-digit number. Because your numbers always start with `601435` the total sum has not less than 2 digits. But at least `6014359999999990` and `6014359999999999` would be validated wrong in V2.

The line `return $check;` can return 0. That way `6014355021355012` or `6014355021355017` are verified as being valid, while they are not.

I would replace the lines:

```
$total = str_split($total);
$check = 10 - $total[1];
$check = $check % 10;
if($check == substr($flybuys, 15, 1))
    return 0;
else
    return $check;
```

with

```
return (substr($flybuys, 15, 1) + $total) % 10;
```

So `V1` and `V2` returns the same value.