# $n = 2; 10-$n = 87

Tags: php, math, operators, phantom-reference

well this is what i am doing:

```
$total = (array_sum($odds))+$evens;
$total = str_split($total);
echo 'total[1]: '.$total[1].'<br />';
echo '10-$total[1]: ' . (10-($total[1]));
```

and the output is:

```
total[1]: 2
10-$total[1]: 87
```

my guess is it is being treated as a string, but how do i fix it?

so, what i want to know is
wh does (10-($total[1])); = 87?

---

**Update:**
yeah my mistake, a phantom 7,
but can anyone now tell me why:

```
echo $flybuys.' % '.$check.'<br />';
   $res = $flybuys % $check;
   echo 'res: '.$res;
```

outputs: 
6014359000000928 % 8
res: 7

Comment: Perhaps you're echoing a spurious __7__ somewhere else in your script

Comment: what's the content of $odds and $evens?

Comment: `10 - '2'` is 8 in PHP.  Also, what do you expect the output the be, and what does `var_export($odds); var_export($evens);` show?  I don't think it's even possible for the result (`10-$total[1]`) to be outside the range [1,10], regardless of what `$total` is.

Comment: this should work, but i guess your "7" comes from somewhere else

Comment: Try seeing the result if you tag a break onto your echo: echo '10-$total[1]: ' . (10-($total[1])).'<br />';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inaccurate modulus result is because 6014359000000928 (~2^52) is beyond the bounds of an int, so PHP interprets it as a float.  That implies you have a 32-bit system (PHP data type sizes vary depending on architecture).  If you need to do math on large numbers, you can use a library like [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).  E.g.:

```
$flybuys = gmp_init("6014359000000928");
$res = gmp_mod($flybuys, 8);
```

Make sure you pass large numbers to GMP as strings.

Answer (score 0):

If it is getting recognized as a string you could try casting it to an int using

```
(int)$total[1];
```

To be honest, you could probably cast the $total array into an int right when you do the string split:

```
(int)$total = ...;
```

Strings that represent numbers can also be cast into (float), and depending on which version of php you have (double).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't reproduce this issue:

```
$total = 2222; // some imaginary number as I don't know your $odds and $evens;
$total = str_split($total);
var_dump($total);
/*
 *array(4) {
 *  [0]=>
 *  string(1) "2"
 *  [1]=>
 *  string(1) "2"
 *  [2]=>
 *  string(1) "2"
 *  [3]=>
 *  string(1) "2"
 *}
 */
var_dump($total[1]);
/*
 * string(1) "2"
 */
var_dump((10-($total[1])));
/*
 * int(8)
 */
```

Absolutely the expected behavior...

Answer (score 0):

I added this as an answer because in a comment is not enough space:

If this is the implementation of the algorithm described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244221/is-there-a-difference-in-the-result-from-these-two-algorithms) i really think that modulo check `6014359000000928 % 8 == 0` shouldn't be there.

For example consider the number with the first 15 digits like that: `6014 3590 0000 062`. For that `evens` is 15, `odds` is 24, `total` is 39 and `check` is 1. Any number modulo 1 is 0. So `6014 3590 0000 0628` is valid as `6014 3590 0000 0620` is or `6014 3590 0000 0627`. That doesn't make sense.

I think you have to check the last digit for equality with `check`. In that case only `6014 3590 0000 0621` would be valid.